# NGRX Can't read entities parameters

Tags: angular7, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

I'm attempting to set up an application that uses NGRX.

I'm having difficulties with accessing returned Entity parameters when a single entity is supposed to be loaded.

I'm also having troubles loading the Entity in a modal form due to not being able to access the entity parameters.

At first the employee list is called from the back end via data.service

data.service.ts :

```
  getEngineers() {
return this.http.get<Engineer[]>(this.engineersUrl);
}
```

which returns all the registered engineers.

Once all of the engineer entries have been listed, engineer-list.componenent.ts adds editEngineer function:

```
  editEngineer(engineer: Engineer) {
this.store.dispatch(new engineerActions.LoadEngineer(engineer.id));
this.openEditDialog(engineer);
console.log(engineer.id, 'selectedEngineersId');
 }

 openEditDialog({ Name, LastName, PhoneNumber, Company, Country }: Engineer) 
{
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EgnineerEditDialogComponent, {
  disableClose: true,
  width: '300px',
  data: {
    Name, LastName, PhoneNumber, Company, Country
  }
 });
}
```

Then the loadEngineer$() effect takes place:

```
@Effect()
loadEngineer$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<engineerActions.LoadEngineer>(
        engineerActions.EngineerActionTypes.LOAD_ENGINEER
    ),
    mergeMap((action: engineerActions.LoadEngineer) =>
        this.dataService.getEngineerById(action.payload).pipe(
            map(
                (engineer: Engineer) =>
                new engineerActions.LoadEngineerSuccess(engineer)
            ),
            catchError(err => of(new engineerActions.LoadEngineerFail(err)))
        )
    ),
);
```

the data.service calls for getEngineerById():

```
  getEngineerById(payload: number): Observable<Engineer> {
     console.log(`${this.engineerUrl}?id=${payload}`);
      return this.http.get<Engineer>(`${this.engineerUrl}?id=${payload}`);
  }
```

Which returns a json response of the selected engineer from a php mysql request:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$emparray = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
echo json_encode( $emparray );
```

The next step is taken by the reducer with the LOAD_ENGINEER_SUCCESS

```
        case engineersActions.EngineerActionTypes.LOAD_ENGINEER_SUCCESS: {
        console.log(action.payload.id, ' - ID of the selected engineer object');
        return engineerAdapter.addOne(action.payload, {
            ...state,
           selectedEngineerId: action.payload.id,
           loading: false,
           loaded: true
        });

    }
```

The problem here is that the console logged response of the reducer

```
console.log(action.payload.id, ' - ID of the selected engineer object');
```

returns `undefined " - ID of the selected engineer object"`
while console logging "action.payload" returns:

```
[{…}]
0:
Company: "Andys Shack"
Country: "EE"
LastName: "Franklichtenshtein    "
Name: "Angus    "
PhoneNumber: "123123123123    "
Registered: "2019-03-09 01:33:28"
id: "19"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

and NGRX also returns an error:

```
entity.js:106 @ngrx/entity: The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned undefined. You should probably provide your own `selectId` implementation. The entity that was passed: [{…}]0: {id: "19", Name: "Angus    ", LastName: "Franklichtenshtein    ", PhoneNumber: "123123123123    ", Country: "EE", …}length: 1__proto__: Array(0) The `selectId` implementation: function (instance) { return instance.id; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The payload is an array, not an object.

```
action.payload[0].id
```